# mysql join select min(date) and max (date) between two tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in my database one is for venue and the other is for booking. what I need is a query to select all the venue that are not booked. See below:

table booking has the following fields:

- bk_id
- venue_id as a foreign key from (booking table)
- start_date (as date type ) //indicate when the venue wouldn't be
- available for booking end_date (as date type )//indicating the end
  date for the booking and from here onward the venue would be
  available for booking

and venue table has following fields:

- venue_id as a primary key
  etc.

What I need is to be able to search for all the venue that are not booked. How should I set my mysql query

Comment: Not booked at all or not booked within a particular date range?

Comment: Can you post sample data and desired output in a tabular form?

Answer (score 0):

For venue not booked on particular date use

```
SELECT * FROM venue WHERE venue_id NOT IN (SELECT venue_id FROM booking WHERE {YOUR_DATE} BETWEEN  start_date AND end_date)
```

For venues that are never booked

```
SELECT * FROM venue WHERE venue_id NOT IN (SELECT venue_id FROM booking)
```

Comment: i tried the first query and i got #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' end_date} BETWEEN 2013-04-01 AND 2013-04-30) LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1 MY ORIGINAL QUERY WAS SELECT * FROM lvenue WHERE venue_id NOT IN (SELECT venue_id FROM booking WHERE {start_date, end_date} BETWEEN  2013-04-01 AND 2013-04-30).

Comment: {YOUR_DATE} is not like what you tried it's like the date on which you want to check a venue booking for example `'2013-04-01' BETWEEN start_date AND  end_date`

Comment: the problem is i have two dates coming from my form the from date which is start date and to which is end date and ai have to pass them in my query as you have suggested SELECT * FROM venue WHERE venue_id NOT IN (SELECT venue_id FROM booking WHERE '2013-04-01', '2013-04-30' BETWEEN start_date AND end_date still getting sql error

Comment: Then try this `SELECT * FROM venue WHERE venue_id NOT IN (SELECT venue_id FROM booking WHERE (start_date BETWEEN  '2013-04-01' AND '2013-04-30') OR (end_date BETWEEN '2013-04-01' AND '2013-04-30'))`